# Custom post type 404 error on "default" or "numeric" permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, permalinks

I wrote a plugin for WP.org that uses a custom post type with the slug "reading-list" and I cannot view mysite.com/reading-list/ when I have either the "default" or "numeric" permalinks setting in wp-admin.

Does anyone know why this would be, i.e. why it only affects these two settings?

I use flush_rewrite_rules() after registering the custom post type in the plugin and I checked all of the parameters according to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments) but nothing seems to help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are trying to access-- `mysite.com/reading-list/`-- is constructed by the WordPress rewrite rules. The path `/reading-list/` doesn't actually exist. If you are using the default `?p=123` links, those rewrite rules are not used. The default links are just `GET` strings.

In other words, since there is nothing at `mysite.com/reading-list/` without the rewrite rules you get a 404.

Without the rewrite rules, you need to access the content using vanilla `GET` syntax. For example, [the "Book" post type used in the Codex as an example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)...

```
function codex_custom_init() {
    $args = array(
      'public' => true,
      'label'  => 'Books'
    );
    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

... is accessed without rewriting as `?book=book-cpt-post-title`. You can't switch off rewriting and also have that non-existent `/reading-list/` directory, though you could create a "Page" called `reading-list` and use that to display your CPT.

Comment: That is what I was thinking.  So is there any way to fix this or work around it?

Comment: @MikeStumpf : see the edit